# "Completing" an LQ decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be a real $m\times n$ matrix with $n>m$. Let $Q_1$ be a $n\times m$ with orthonormal columns such that
$$
AQ_1 = L
$$
where $L$ is of dimension $m\times m$ and lower triangular.

> **Question:** Is it always possible to find a $n\times (n-m)$ matrix $Q_2$ such that $Q:=[Q_1\, |\, Q_2]$ is orthogonal and 
>   $$
> AQ = [L\, |\, \mathbf{0}_{m\times (n-m)}],
> $$ 
>   where $\mathbf{0}_{m\times (n-m)}$ denotes a $m\times (n-m)$ zero matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ has maximum rank $m$. So rank of its null space $\ge n-m$. Hence we can get $n-m$ independent vectors from $Null(A)$ which constitutes $Q_2$ such that $AQ_2=0$. The columns of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ will be independent. We can carry out a Gram Schmidt orthogonalization to make the matrix $Q$ orthogonal.

Comment: So, in general (i.e., without applying a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization step), it is not possible to find $Q_2$ such that $Q$ is orthogonal. Right?

Comment: @Ludwig Why would we not be able to apply the GS orthogonalization?

Comment: My question asks if $Q$ is orthogonal "as it is", not after applying another transformation.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean that we can apply a GS orthogonalization only on $Q_2$ in order to make $Q$ orthogonal?

Comment: We can just choose an orthogonal basis of $Null(A)$, that would do

Comment: Ok, this ensures that the columns of $Q_2$ are orthonormal. Now, it is not clear to me why these columns should be also orthogonal to the columns of the "fixed" $Q_1$.

Comment: Because $Q_1$ is already orthogonal and consists of independent vectors from column space of $A$.

Comment: Also the GS orthogonalization of the entire matrix $Q$, would leave the columns of $Q_1$ unchanged, as they are already orthogonal, and only orthogonalize columns of $Q_2$

Comment: My point is that in general the column space of a matrix is *not* orthogonal to the null space (indeed it holds $\mathrm{Null}(A)=[\mathrm{Im}(A^\top)]^\perp$). So I don't see why the fact that $Q_1$ consists of orthonormal vectors from column space of $A$ should imply that $Q_1$ is orthogonal to $Q_2$.